# suppose $f:[1,\infty] \rightarrow R, f(1)=0, f'$ is continuous and bounded and $f' \in L^2([1, \infty])$, show $g=f(x)/x \in L^2([1, \infty])$ .

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

It's a problem in Bass's real analysis book. suppose $f:[1,\infty] \rightarrow R, f(1)=0, f'exist$ and is continuous and bounded and $f' \in L^2([1, \infty])$, let $g(x)=f(x)/x,$ show $g \in L^2([1, \infty])$ .

**Progress**

By the assumption, I know $f$ is absolutely continous, then I get the relationship between $f$ and $f'$ by property of AC,  $f(x)=f(1)+ \int_{1}^{x} f'(t)dt=\int_{1}^{x} f'(t)dt$,then by H$\ddot{o}$lder inequality, $|f(x)|\leq (\int_{1}^{x} |f'(t)|^{2}dt)^{1/2}*(\int_{1}^{x} 1^{2}dt)^{1/2} $. Then the first part is bounded M,  if the second part is finite, I can get the relationship between $f ~and~ f'$. But now the second part$(\int_{1}^{x} 1^{2}dt)^{1/2}$ which is not finite, then $\int |g|^2dx \leq \int M^2*(x-1)/x^2=M^2\int (1/x-1/x^2)dx $, $1/x $is not in $L^2$ and we can not get the result.what can I do next? thanks

Comment: The second part is finite. It's $\sqrt{x-1}$. Recall that $g(x)=f(x)/x$, so this $x$ is going to help.

Comment: What's $L^p$ denote?

Comment: @Woodface: however, from $f(x)\ll\sqrt{x}$ it does not follow that $\frac{f(x)}{x}\in L^2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Good point; looks like one needs a Hilbert-Schmidt kind of bound to show that the operator $f'\mapsto g$ is bounded on $L^2$.

Comment: what's Hilbert-Schmidt kind of bound?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio please answer.

Comment: @AlecTeal: I just answered. The result follows by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality twice and integration by parts.

Comment: @AlecTeal: $L^p$ is the space of functions for which $\int_{1}^{+\infty}|f(x)|^p\,dx$ is finite, in this case.

Comment: Is it usually on $[0,\infty]$ @JackD'Aurizio? and is it not such that $\left(\int^\infty_1|f(x)|^pdx\right)^\frac{1}{p}<\infty$? (That's the norm as in the norm $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}$ - sorry for being so pedantic but this is why I asked.

Comment: @AlecTeal: in general, $L^p(I)$ is the set of functions for which $\int_{I}|f(x)|^p\,dx$ is finite, and we denote with $\|f\|_p$ the $p$-th root of the previous integral. In this case, we are working over $I=[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio may I ask one more question? (assuming yes:) what is the motivation of the $p^\text{th}$ root? part? It is clearly true that $x$ being finite $\iff(x)^\frac{1}{p}$ is finite (finite ^ p = finite) - this is a fairly new area to me by the way.

Comment: @AlecTeal: we want that the $L_p$-norms to be homogeneous, hence we take the square root of the integral of the square, the third root of the integral of the cube and so on. Assuming that $f(x)$ gives the length of something in meters, we want that $\|f\|_p$ is in meters, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$ f(x) = \int_{1}^{x}f'(y)\,dy $$
it follows that:
$$ |f(x)| \leq \int_{1}^{x}|f'(y)|\,dy \leq \sqrt{\int_{1}^{x}f'(y)^2\,dy\cdot\int_{1}^{x}1\,dy}\leq \sqrt{x-1}\,\|f'\|_2\ll\sqrt{x}$$
hence:
$$ I_N=\int_{1}^{N}\frac{f(x)^2}{x^2}\,dx=\left.-\frac{f(x)^2}{x}\right|_{1}^{N}+2\int_{1}^{N}\frac{f(x)\,f'(x)}{x}\,dx $$
always by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, fulfills the bound:
$$ I_N \leq 2\|f'\|_2+2\|f'\|_2 \sqrt{I_N}\leq 2\|f'\|_2 \max(1,\sqrt{I_N}) $$
and assuming $I_N\geq 1$ it follows that:
$$ I_N \leq 4\|f'\|_2^2 $$
from which $g\in L^2$ follows.

Comment: @mathsara: nope. The integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is $-\frac{1}{x}$, the derivatives of $f(x)^2$ is $2f'(x)f(x)$.

Comment: @mathsara: you're welcome.